# Selection of open-source MDM server

Tags: ios, iphone, mdm, configuration-profile

I am quite new to MDM & iOS profile configuration. Please bear with me.

I am creating an application for school management who wants blocks all non-system iOS applications (starting with iOS then later android) on a the campus during school hours. Students install the iOS profile by going to my website or through an app. I have scheduler running on my server which at specified time & based on their location applies restriction and all non-system apps will be hidden from iPhone (this is for non-supervised iPhone/iPad).

I have couple of questions in this regard

1. Will iOS developer license (99$) work for above scenario or requires an enterprise license (299$)?
2. [ws02 EMM](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/) is the right choice for me or should I use [MDM-Server](https://github.com/project-imas/mdm-server)

This will be low-cost product so can't invest in external MDM servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. - MDM Capability has nothing to do with how you distribute the application , it doesn't matter if it's an AppStore app or Enterprise app if the device is registered to MDM and the app uses MDM api (NSUserDefaults with "com.apple.configuration.managed" key) then it will work.
   - An application can't "hide" itself , it totally depends on the DEVICE restrictions enforced by MDM SERVER.
2. If you intend to apply this to android then use  one that allows multiple platforms.

Comment: So you mean to say that I don't require enterprise iOS license?

Comment: You don't need any license to develop mdm app , However you will need a license to distribute it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. My app is going to be available from iTunes & it's going to need above capabilities. Will it require enterprise license & developer license?

Comment: Only AppStore license.